# Can't add foreign key constraints in sqlite using java

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

My table is :

```
Statement s5 = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet res5 = s5.executeQuery("Select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = 'actor_director'");
             if(!res5.next()){
                Statement ad = conn.createStatement();
                ad.executeUpdate("create table actor_director(actor_ID integer, director_ID integer," 
                        + "foreign key(actor_ID) references actor(actor_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE," 
                        + "foreign key(director_ID) references director(director_ID)) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE"); 

             }
```

and i also did :

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
    config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:movieandtvseries.db", config.toProperties());
    return conn;
}
```

When i run the program i get this error :

```
SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "ON": syntax error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in the line:

```
          + "foreign key(director_ID) references director(director_ID)) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE");
```

There is an extra ')' after 'director_ID'. There is also a ')' missing after the last 'CASCADE' and before the double quote.